# Mixing dynamic imports with if conditions

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I know that currently we can use a dynamic import inside an es-module to lazily import code:

```
import * as React from 'react'

const SmileyFace = React.lazy(() => import('./smiley-face'))

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
        <SmileyFace />
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But I want to not put that import statement on top - but inside an if block because i don't want to load it unless my viewport size is bigger than mobile.

so can i do this ?

```
import * as React from 'react'

let SmileyFace = null;
let isMobile = innerWidth > 400;

function importIfNecessary(){
  if(isMobile) {
     SmileyFace = React.lazy(() => import('./smiley-face')) 
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
  isMobile ? <>Bland Mobile code</> : 
    <div>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
        <SmileyFace />
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smiley will only import if it is being rendered.

```
// parent.js
import * as React from 'react'
const SmileyFace = React.lazy(() => import('./Smiley')) 

let isMobile = innerWidth > 400;

function App() {
  return (
      isMobile ? <>Bland Mobile code</> : <React.Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}><Smiley /></React.Suspense>
  )
}

// Smiley.js
export const Smiley = () => {
  return (
    [... whatever your smiley face is]
  )
}
```

(Not tested, let me know if it works). There's probably a cleaner solution, but this should get you started.

Comment: i read some material online - and yes i think this is the correct answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to use asynchronous import and store it in a variable, you will need to make the parent block an `async` function, in your case the function `importIfNecessary` should be an `async` function, declared like: `async function importIfNecessary()...`.
Then, in order to use the module on condition, load it like this: `const module = await import(path);`

Now, the solution aside, I would not suggest using this method if you are going to use the `module` quite often in your project, as I once read an article that said `prefer loading commonly used modules(ones that you definitely will use) in the global scope as webpack will perform tree-shaking and build size would reduce` or something along those lines.

Here is a reference article for your question: [Dynamic Import Conditionally](https://dmitripavlutin.com/ecmascript-modules-dynamic-import/)